# JUnit test description

Tags: java, testing, junit

Is it possible in JUnit to add a brief description of the test for the future reader (e.g. what's being tested, some short explanation, expected result, ...)? I mean something like in ScalaTest, where I can write:

```
test("Testing if true holds") {
  assert(true)
}
```

Ideal approach would be using some annotation, e.g.

```
@Test
@TestDescription("Testing if true holds")
public void testTrue() {
    assert(true);
}
```

Therefore, if I run such annotated tests using Maven (or some similar tool), I could have similar output to the one I have in SBT when using ScalaTest:

```
- Testing if entity gets saved correctly
- Testing if saving fails when field Name is not specified
- ...
```

Currently I can either use terribly long method names or write javadoc comments, which are 
not present in the build output.

Thank you.

Comment: A common approach is just to have the description in the test name, e.g. `public void testIfTrueHoldsForNegativeValues()`. I don't see a need for a special annotation to do this.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the long names, as they are quite common.  You can write them smartly, e.g. `entityIsSavedCorrectly`, `saveFailsWhenNameMissing`, etc.  Be sure to leave off the `test` prefix as it is redundant (esp. with the `@Test` annotation).  ScalaTest is only giving a string where JUnit's method name would be, so all you are "losing" is spaces.  If you must have the descriptions you can always stick them on individual asserts.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

In JUnit 5, there is [@DisplayName](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org.junit.jupiter.api/org/junit/jupiter/api/DisplayName.html) annotation:

> @DisplayName is used to declare a custom display name for the
>   annotated test class or test method. Display names are typically used
>   for test reporting in IDEs and build tools and may contain spaces,
>   special characters, and even emoji.

Example:

```
@Test
@DisplayName("Test if true holds")
public void checkTrue() {
    assertEquals(true, true);
}
```

Comment: There is a plugin for Android, if you want to use JUnit5: https://github.com/mannodermaus/android-junit5

Comment: The inclusion of emojis is what sold me on using it

Comment: This annotation is intended to be a more readable version of the test method name. Is there another way to convey a long description of the test in JUnit without resorting to comments in the source code?

Answer (score 18):

TestNG does it like this, which to me is the neatest solution:

```
@Test(description="My funky test")  
public void testFunk() {  
    ...  
}
```

See http://testng.org/javadocs/org/testng/annotations/Test.html for more information.

Comment: I am sorry to mark it down. The question is about Junit not TestNG. We all know TestNG supports description.

Comment: It is relevant information. Contrary to what has been said, not everyone knows TestNG and not everyone knows that unlike JUnit, it supports descriptions. I think it is worth suggesting it even though OP's question is about JUnit. Readers may not be fixed on the framework they use.

Comment: At least for me this comment was helpful and I did not know TestNG, just because I just recently started with Java coming from TypeScript, where I used Mocha - I guess if you were not a JavaScript-Developer you wouldn't know about Mocha, right?

Comment: Upvote from me too. Thank you for sharing knowledge beyond the boundaries of the question.

Answer (score 15):

Not exactly what you are looking for, but you can provide a description on any `assert` methods.

Something like:

```
@Test
public void testTrue() {
    assertTrue("Testing if true holds", true);
}
```

Comment: It will work, but I think it is not good way of writing description. It will create confusion to new developers.

Answer (score 7):

I prefer to follow a standard format when testing in JUnit. The name of the test would be

```
test[method name]_[condition]_[outcome]
```

for Example:

```
 @Test
 public void testCreateObject_nullField_errorMessage(){}

 @Test
 public void testCreateObject_validObject_objectCreated(){}
```

I think this approach is helpful when doing TDD, because you can just start writing all the test names, so you know what you need to test / develop.

Still I would welcome a test description functionality from JUnit.

And this is certainly better than other tests I have seen in the past like:

```
@Test public void testCreateObject1(){}
@Test public void testCreateObject2(){}
@Test public void testCreateObject3(){}
```

or

```
@Test public void testCreateObjectWithNullFirstNameAndSecondNameTooLong(){}
```

Comment: Isn't the `test` prefix a piece of legacy ?

Comment: yes, "test" can be dropped, just a bad habit of mine

Answer (score 2):

You can name the test method after the test:

```
public void testThatOnePlusOneEqualsTwo() {
  assertEquals(2, 1 + 1);
}
```

This will show up in Eclipse, Surefire, and most other runners.

Answer (score 1):

The **detailed solution** would be: You could add a `Logger` to your test, to log the results to a File. [See log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/), for example. Then you can read the results in the File and also print successfull statements, what `assert`statemens cannot.

The **simple solution**: You can add a `JDoc` description to every test method, this will be outlined, if you generate the JavaDoc.

Also every `assert`statement can provide a Message, that will be printed, whenever the `assert` fails.

```
/**
 * test the List#size() increasement after adding an Object to a List.
 */
public void testAdd(){
  List<Object> list = new LinkedList<>(); 
  list.add(new Object());
  assertEquals("size should be 1, because of adding an Object", 1, list.size());
}
```

Do NOT use `System.out.println("your message");` because you don't know how the tests will be executed and if the environment does not provide a console, your messages will not be displayed.