# How to write description in Junit?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, tdd, junit5

I am using [Test Driven Development](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development) approach for coding and testing various modules.

---

**What I want to do? :**
I want to write some description to all my test cases so it could easily be readable for anyone.

**How I am writing description right now?**

```
@Test
@DisplayName("Description about my test case.")
public void addTwoObjects_onInvalidMapping_shouldReturnAnError(){
  .
  . 
  .
}
```

**How I don't want to write description?**: I don't want to use comments to write  description of code.

---

**Also, I don't want to use the `DisplayName()` annotation** which I am currently using in JUNIT5. As this annotation by my understanding is meant for renaming technical function names and not for writing description.

Reference:

> Test classes and test methods can declare custom display names via @DisplayName — with spaces, special characters, and even emojis — that will be displayed in test reports and by test runners and IDEs [[2](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-display-names)]

---

This Question is similar to [*JUnit test description*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13159293/642706), but for two differences: (a) Asking about the current generation of JUnit 5, and (b) Explicitly asking for place to put a lengthy description rather than simply renaming the test method’s name.

Comment: Would you want to do something with the description?

Comment: @johanneslink I want to write description to my test cases. So, that in case if anyone in company maybe new intern comes. He will get some insights what the code is doing even the non technical staff will get some understanding from the description. More important sometimes I even forget :) what my test case were for after a month. Though function name aid in remembrance but not gives clear picture.

Comment: @ZahidKhan - `I want to write description to my test cases. So, that in case if anyone in company maybe new intern comes. He will get some insights what the code is doing even the non technical staff will get some understanding from the description....` - [Javadoc](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/javadoc-tool.html) is meant for this purpose only. If you do not want to use it, its your problem; Java will not change for such odd deslikes.

Comment: I have to agree that Javadoc in your tests’ source code (not your app source code) seems appropriate to me. Do you know that Java comes with tools to generate nicely formatted web pages (HTML) like you see in the [Java API documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/index.html)? I suggest you edit your question to explain how Javadoc does not address your needs. And see [Wikipedia to learn more about Javadoc](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Javadoc).

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash I am using javadocs when writing my coding part. But when I write test cases I believe there should be some annotation available in the Junit for such cases. Testing (JUNIT) and coding (JAVA) should be separated.

Comment: @ZahidKhan We are suggesting Javadoc in your *test* source code, not your *app* source code. This approach maintains the separation you speak of. Perhaps someone can write an Answer showing an example of such Javadoc.

Comment: @BasilBourque  thanks for your valuable suggestion and edits :) I think I can make some more amendments to this question or add some more explanation later - I believe Javadocs doesn't addressed my problem correctly. Or something is missing in JUnits. ( Just an intuition..)

Comment: You can always create your own annotation. But the question remains: What do you want to do with the description apart from seeing it close to the test code and in generated docs, both aspects being well covered by Javadoc.

Answer (score 3):

You are correct about the `DisplayName` annotation. The intention there is to simply provide a more readable name than the method’s name. This name is meant to be picked up by tooling that presents a user-interface to monitor the running of your tests. That annotation is not appropriate for lengthy description and notes.

## Javadoc

The [Javadoc](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Javadoc) facility in Java enables you to attach lengthy descriptions and notes to your source code. Java includes tools to extract the content of your Javadoc for presentation as nicely formatted pages written in auto-generated HTML.

Your JUnit tests are Java source code. So your test source code can carry Javadoc just like your app source code can carry Javadoc.

Your [IDE](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) will likely have features to assist in writing the Javadoc.

You wrote:

> in case if anyone in company maybe new intern comes. He will get some insights what the code is doing even the non technical staff will get some understanding from the description.

Indeed, this exactly what Javadoc is for. Being embedded within the source means you cannot lose the content of your description and notes.

Javadoc on the source code of your tests seems to meet to your needs.